# Как получить переменную из массива node.js

Tags: javascript

Хочу получить переменную из массива. Пример массива:

```js
const arr = {
  "!name": "value"
}
```

Как мне получить переменную `!name`? И подскажите как правильно загуглить этот вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Как получить значение: `arr['!name']`. Это не переменная, а свойство объекта (не путать с массивом)... Как загуглить: `mdn js руководство`.

Comment: @yar85 Большое спасибо!

Comment: Еще https://learn.javascript.ru - но там теперь есть ошибки в некоторых статьях (редакторы постарались), и при обучении JavaScript'у по этому ресурсу очень желательно сверяться с другими источниками - тот же MDN (желательно непереводной анлийский) в качестве справочника хорошо подойдет. Это все конечно вводный материал именно в язык, и перед ним хорошо бы изучить общие основы программирования (что это такое, как работает комп, типы данных и их представление, структуры, алгоритмизация).

Comment: А если не хочется изучать все последовательно, то конкретно о работе с объектами [вот статейка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).